# regular expression for allowing words and spaces only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input name="city" ng-pattern="([\w ]+)" 
        invalid-message="'City is invalid.'" 
           ng-model="city" type="text" 
            required-message="'You must enter a city.'" required >
```

I have an input field as above where i have to allow only `alphabets and spaces alone`, but the above one fails... throwing me `"City is invalid"`. I tried with different combination of pattern but all fails... `ng-pattern="([a-zA-z ]+)"`

Comment: `a-zA-z` should be `a-zA-Z`

Comment: It still fails...

Comment: isn't `ng-pattern` supposed to take a string value? Probably need to bind it to a value or wrap it in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ng-pattern` expression doesn't evaluate to a string or regular expression object.

If you want to hard-code a regular expression, wrap it in quotes so that it's evaluated as a string:

```
ng-pattern="'[A-Za-z ]+'"
```

Alternatively, bind `ng-pattern` to a variable:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
ng-pattern="regex"
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$scope.regex = '[A-Za-z ]+';
```

---

Note that the `^` and `$` are unnecessary as they are implied when passing a string parameter:

> If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in `^` and `$` characters.

Answer (score 0):

The following matches any character from a-z as well as whitespaces, from the beginning to the end of the string:

^[A-Za-z\s]*$

Comment: [Per the docs "If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters."](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).